# Android List view to new intent/activity stops media player when going back

Tags: android, listview, media-player, android-intent, tabview

What I essentially have is `tabview` with a `listview` inside. When an item in the `listview` is pressed, a new `intent` is created to take them to a different view. Inside this view is a `mediaplayer`. My problem is that when I try to go back to the `tabview` my `mediaplayer` stops playing and the `view` doesn't stay intact. Is there anyway to fix this? I essentially want to be able to go back and forth and have the view with the mediaplayer stay intact. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

EDIT:
I solved this by using an activity group and by having the media player in a service

Comment: Can you clarify: You say your tabview has a tab with a listview, which upon clicking an item opens your mediaplayer in a separate activity. But you say when you return to your tabview your mediaplayer stops playing. Is the mediaplayer inside the tabview?

Comment: I think you may have to implement your media player as a background service instead of activity...

Comment: @Jack- When i click an item, it opens a new intent with a next activity. This activity has its own layout an java file in which inside is the media player. When I go back to my tab view, it stops the music currently playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using an activity group and having the media player in a service running in the background